# Populate a drop down list using knockout and an AJAX call to database

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

I have a drop down list with a few values.

Based on which value is selected, I want to populate a second drop down list with values from a database.

I'm using knockout and have the AJAX query set up to pull the data back from the database and into my javascript code.

Whenever I select an item in the first drop down list, I can see all of the correct values for the second drop down list if I do an alert or log to the console.  Everything works correctly as far as grabbing the selected value from the first drop down list, sending it to the database via AJAX and then returning the list of values for the second drop down list.

The problem is that the second drop down list is not populated with those values.  I figure it is a relatively simple fix to do with my data binding with knockout, but I'm not sure exactly what to try next.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you!

```
self.getSomeValuesFromDb = function (url, valueToSendToDb) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: url,
            data: {
                valueToSendToDb: valueToSendToDb
            },
            success: function (response) {
                self.valueObsArray = ko.observableArray([]);
                self.selected_value = ko.observable();
                $.each(response, function (index, theValue) {
                    self.valueObsArray.push(response[index]);
                });
                alert(self.valueObsArray());
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log("There has been an error retrieving the values from the database.");
            }     
        });





<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 control-label">DDL 2:</label>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9" data-bind="with: $parent.popup.selected_valueDropDownList1">
<select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $root.getSomeValuesFromDb('/SomeValue/Test','theValue'), value: $root.valueObsArray, optionsCaption: 'Select a value'"></select></div></div>
```

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: @M.Ihsan I have added the code.  You will see I make the AJAX call and then add the returned values into the observable array.  The alert after the $.each gives me all of the correct values for the second drop down list, so I think that part is correct and that the values are indeed in the observable array.  I then to bind the value of the drop down list to that observable array, and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

From your code above, you just need to initialize `valueObsArray` outside `getSomeValuesFromDb`. Then inside `getSomeValuesFromDb` you need to set the array of `valueObsArray` back to empty with the following code

```
valueObsArray([]);
```

It will look like this:

```
self.valueObsArray = ko.observableArray([]);
self.getSomeValuesFromDb = function (url, valueToSendToDb) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: url,
        data: {
            valueToSendToDb: valueToSendToDb
        },
        success: function (response) {
            self.valueObsArray([]);
            self.selected_value = ko.observable();
            $.each(response, function (index, theValue) {
                self.valueObsArray.push(response[index]);
            });
            alert(self.valueObsArray());
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log("There has been an error retrieving the values from the database.");
        }     
    });
```

Otherwise you can also use `pureComputed` to do ajax call to get values for the second dropdown when a value is selected from the first dropdown:

```js
var simpleListModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.firstOptions = ko.observable(["", "Apple", "Orange", "Mango"]);
  self.selectedFirstOption = ko.observable("");
  self.secondOptions = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    if(self.selectedFirstOption() === "") return [];
    else {
      // do ajax call here
      var number = 0;
      return ko.utils.arrayMap(self.firstOptions(), function(item) {
        return self.selectedFirstOption() + number++;
      });
    }
  }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(simpleListModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>
  <select data-bind="options: firstOptions, value: selectedFirstOption"></select>
</div>
<div>
  <select data-bind="options: secondOptions"></select>
</div>
```